# Apache Spark group by combining types and sub types

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have this dataset in spark,

```
val sales = Seq(
  ("Warsaw", 2016, "facebook","share",100),
  ("Warsaw", 2017, "facebook","like",200),
  ("Boston", 2015,"twitter","share",50),
  ("Boston", 2016,"facebook","share",150),
  ("Toronto", 2017,"twitter","like",50)
).toDF("city", "year","media","action","amount")
```

I can now group this by city and media like this,

```
val groupByCityAndYear = sales
  .groupBy("city", "media") 
  .count()
groupByCityAndYear.show()

+-------+--------+-----+
|   city|   media|count|
+-------+--------+-----+
| Boston|facebook|    1|
| Boston| twitter|    1|
|Toronto| twitter|    1|
| Warsaw|facebook|    2|
+-------+--------+-----+
```

But, how can I do combine media and action together in one column, so the expected output should be,

```
+-------+--------+-----+
| Boston|facebook|    1|
| Boston| share  |    2|
| Boston| twitter|    1|
|Toronto| twitter|    1|
|Toronto| like   |    1|
| Warsaw|facebook|    2|
| Warsaw|share   |    1|
| Warsaw|like    |    1|
+-------+--------+-----+
```

Comment: is it pyspark or scala?

Comment: I am happy with any solution. Both are fine. Even spark-sql is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine `media` and `action` columns as `array` column, `explode` it, then do `groupBy` `count`:

```
sales.select(
    $"city", explode(array($"media", $"action")).as("mediaAction")
).groupBy("city", "mediaAction").count().show()

+-------+-----------+-----+
|   city|mediaAction|count|
+-------+-----------+-----+
| Boston|      share|    2|
| Boston|   facebook|    1|
| Warsaw|      share|    1|
| Boston|    twitter|    1|
| Warsaw|       like|    1|
|Toronto|    twitter|    1|
|Toronto|       like|    1|
| Warsaw|   facebook|    2|
+-------+-----------+-----+
```

Or assuming `media` and `action` doesn't intersect (the two columns don't have common elements):

```
sales.groupBy("city", "media").count().union(
    sales.groupBy("city", "action").count()
).show
+-------+--------+-----+
|   city|   media|count|
+-------+--------+-----+
| Boston|facebook|    1|
| Boston| twitter|    1|
|Toronto| twitter|    1|
| Warsaw|facebook|    2|
| Boston|   share|    2|
| Warsaw|   share|    1|
| Warsaw|    like|    1|
|Toronto|    like|    1|
+-------+--------+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks. This is just a sample dataset. How this solution will perform for 6 billion records. ? I am skeptical about using explode.

Comment: assuming media and action doesn't intersect: -- Can you explain this ? Thanks again.

Comment: I am not sure whether `explode` is very inefficient but you can do two group bys and then combine the results.

Comment: *doesn't intersect* I mean there are no common elements.

Comment: Hi. One more thing, is it possible to do case statement on second level. Lets say we are doing the second solution, first group by is fine, in the second group by, I want to have something like, if action is share, then duplicate that record. Lets take 5th record in second solution, it should be Boston,share1,2 and Boston,share2,2

Comment: I believe it's possible but not straightforward, you might have to use `UDF` to manipulate the column, for instance turn the column into an array column conditionally, explode it and then group by.

Comment: I have never written any UDF. Thanks anyways. I think, I should ask that as a new question.