# Duplicating the record count in apache spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This is an extension of this question, [Apache Spark group by combining types and sub types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50146145/apache-spark-group-by-combining-types-and-sub-types).

```
val sales = Seq(
  ("Warsaw", 2016, "facebook","share",100),
  ("Warsaw", 2017, "facebook","like",200),
  ("Boston", 2015,"twitter","share",50),
  ("Boston", 2016,"facebook","share",150),
  ("Toronto", 2017,"twitter","like",50)
).toDF("city", "year","media","action","amount")
```

All good with that solution, however the expected output should be counted in different categories conditionally.

So, the output should look like,

```
+-------+--------+-----+
| Boston|facebook|    1|
| Boston| share1 |    2|
| Boston| share2 |    2|
| Boston| twitter|    1|
|Toronto| twitter|    1|
|Toronto| like   |    1|
| Warsaw|facebook|    2|
| Warsaw|share1  |    1|
| Warsaw|share2  |    1|
| Warsaw|like    |    1|
+-------+--------+-----+
```

Here if the action is share, I need to have that counted both in share1 and share2. When I count it programmatically, I use case statement and say case when action is share, share1 = share1 +1 , share2 = share2+1

But how can I do this in Scala or pyspark or sql ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `filter` and `unions` should give you your desired output

```
val media = sales.groupBy("city", "media").count()

val action = sales.groupBy("city", "action").count().select($"city", $"action".as("media"), $"count")

val share = action.filter($"media" === "share")

  media.union(action.filter($"media" =!= "share"))
      .union(share.withColumn("media", lit("share1")))
      .union(share.withColumn("media", lit("share2")))
      .show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+-------+--------+-----+
|city   |media   |count|
+-------+--------+-----+
|Boston |facebook|1    |
|Boston |twitter |1    |
|Toronto|twitter |1    |
|Warsaw |facebook|2    |
|Warsaw |like    |1    |
|Toronto|like    |1    |
|Boston |share1  |2    |
|Warsaw |share1  |1    |
|Boston |share2  |2    |
|Warsaw |share2  |1    |
+-------+--------+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks. But last two records in your output has facebook1 and facebook2 which I don't want.

Comment: If you look at my question, I have mentioned, I need to count them conditionally only if its share.

Comment: Also, can you explain what you are doing in the UDF please.

Comment: Yeah because the input data has share for Warshaw, so it is in output as share1 and share2. But not as facebook1 & facebook2. Thanks for helping out, but I think your output and my output is different.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170259/discussion-between-ds-user-and-ramesh-maharjan).